# Run a function if form is successful

Tags: php, sql

I am having issues getting my code to run:

```php
if(isset($_POST["associate"])) {

  $partner = $_POST['partner'];
  $location = $_POST['location'];

  function Associate($partner, $location) {

    if ($commit = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO partners_locations (partners_locations_id, partner_id, location_id) VALUES (NULL, '".$partner."', '".$location."')")) {

      echo 'Success';

    } else {

      echo 'Failed to commit to Database';

    }
  }

  Associate($partner, $location);

} else {

 echo 'Failed';

}
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/myremovalsquote/public_html/wp-content/plugins/myremovalsquote/inc/partners.php on line 138

**line 138** = *if ($commit = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO partners_locations (partners_locations_id, partner_id, location_id) VALUES (NULL, '".$partner."', '".$location."')")) {*

Comment: $wpdb is not defined in the scope of the Associate() function. either pass it along as a parameter to the function, drop the function or make it global (worst).

Comment: Great that worked, so do I just call it in every function I do? as I will be creating many functions which use $wpdb

Comment: You need to pass `$updb` to your function as well. Otherwise it is outside the scope and cannot be used. You could do it like `function Associate($partner, $location, $updb) { // ...`

Comment: either that or take advantage of OOP (extending the db class / adding your own methods, etc), you have many ways to deal with this and build your architecture around it.

Comment: Its a bad practice to write a function in an if condition.You just call a function on if condition and write your function out of if-else.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["associate"])) {

  $partner = $_POST['partner'];
  $location = $_POST['location'];

  function Associate($partner, $location) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ($commit = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO partners_locations (partners_locations_id, partner_id, location_id) VALUES (NULL, '".$partner."', '".$location."')")) {

  echo 'Success';

} else {

  echo 'Failed to commit to Database';

}
 }

 Associate($partner, $location);

 } else {

echo 'Failed';
```

}